# Xamarin.Forms - The mechanism about text contain in x:String in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm curious about why x:String or other primitive types that can contain text in the xaml open and close tab.

show as below code：

```
    <x:String>String content here!</x:String>
```

Like Xamarin.Forms "Label", it decorate [ContentProperty("Text")] on the top of the class, and we can write code like

```
   <Label>Hello</Label>
```

But, in the x:String tag, I could not found any decorate on it.

Can anyone help me to solve my question?

Comment: The definition of `<x:String>` is determined by whatever namespace `x` is defined to be, at top of XAML. Read about those declaration lines, and how to find the corresponding spec for each namespace declared. (I realize that `x` is one of the "standard" ones, but I decided it was more helpful to explain the fundamental principle here; then you can explore any declarations you want.) Sorry, I don't recall what link explains the "standard" namespaces.

Comment: So you mean, the type in namespace x will auto handle all this thing just like UI control decorate "ContentProperty", but in another way.

Comment: It is bit of different from `ContentProperty` , `ContentProperty` is used to set an existing property as the content, but <x:String> here is just a kind of `markup extension ` which we can set the value inside it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's forget about `x:String` and focus on `Thickness` for the moment. Obviously you can create an instance of `Thickness` this way:

```
<Thickness>1,1,1,1</Thickness>
```

Now, let's compare this to creating a `Label`:

```
<Label>Hello</Label>
```

Although both lines look similar, they are doing different things. With the `Label`, it creates an instance of `Label` (using the default parameterless constructor) and assigns `Hello` to its `Text` property (as instructed by `[ContentProperty("Text")]` attribute on `Label` class). But this is not the case with `Thickness`.  You cannot just create an instance of `Thickness` and assign the value `1,1,1,1` to one of its properties. There are two problems:

1. `Thickness` does not have a string property to accept a comma-separated value and initialize its `Bottom`, `Right`, `Top`, `Left` properties.
2. Even worse, `Thickness` is not a class. It's a struct, hence it does not have a parameterless constructor. So how can Xamarin decide what arguments need to be passed to its constructor?

Now you can clearly see that `ContentProperty` attribute is not what makes us able to do: `<Thickness>1,1,1,1</Thickness>`. Here Xamarin.Forms takes the string value `1,1,1,1` and converts it to an instance of `Thickness`. This is done via `TypeConverter`s in Xamarin.Forms. You can verify this by checking `[TypeConverter(typeof(ThicknessTypeConverter))]` on `Thickness` struct.

I think the idea is the same with the built-in primitive types in Xamarin.Forms. For example, when you write `<x:Boolean>True</x:Boolean>`, Xamarin.Forms takes the string `True` and converts it to a `System.Boolean` with the help of its internal `TypeConverter`s.

**Bonus**: If you want to achieve the same behavior with your own custom structs (I don't think it's possible for classes) you can do as follows:

1. Create a custom `TypeConverter` to instruct `Xamarin.Forms` how it should convert string values to instances of your struct:

   ```
   public class MyPointConverter : Xamarin.Forms.TypeConverter
   {
       public override object ConvertFromInvariantString(string value)
       {
           var parts = value.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.None);

           if (parts.Length != 2
               || !int.TryParse(parts[0], out var x)
               || !int.TryParse(parts[1], out var y))
           {
               return base.ConvertFromInvariantString(value);
           }

           var myPoint = new MyPoint(x, y);

           return myPoint;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Decorate your struct with `TypeConverterAttribute` to show a custom `TypeConverter` is available for this type:

   ```
   [Xamarin.Forms.TypeConverter(typeof(MyPointConverter))]
   public struct MyPoint
   {
       public int X { get; set; }
       public int Y { get; set; }

       public MyPoint(int x, int y)
       {
           this.X = x;
           this.Y = y;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create instances of your struct in Xaml:

   ```
   <ResourceDictionary>
       <local:MyPoint x:Key="MyPoint">1,5</local:MyPoint>
   </ResourceDictionary>
   ```

Comment: Wow, That is really clear for me. Thank you. I'm appreciate.